# ember data-binding from parent to child

Tags: ember.js

i have just started learning ember 1 week ago, and i'm little confused about data-biding :

- i have `index` controller that have a  `foor` property,
- `test-component` that have a its `bar` property comming from the index controller `foo` property

---

**index**

index.hbs // template

```
parent value  : {{foo}}

{{test-component bar=foo }}
```

index.js // controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  foo: "",
});
```

test-component // template

```
child value {{bar}}
```

test-component // component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

let TestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
});

TestComponent.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: ['bar'],
});

export default TestComponent;
```

---

what confuse is :

1. if write the component in my index template as `{{test-component foo}}` , i get only one-way data-binding, that mean if i change the `bar` property in the component, the `foo` property don't change.
2. if i use a `{{input value=bar}}` inside my component, i can see that both `bar` and `foo` get updated, so bar is binded to both foo and input value component ?? how its is working(PS : as i said in question 1, foo get updated only if i write in my index template `{{test-component bar=foo}}`

and thanks everyone.

Comment: refer this..[this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/995e2d2e0d5e6ae54afb6f3095c3d1efb20cdcfc) might give more insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The behavior where positional parameters have a one-way binding and named parameters have a two-way binding was a [bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14408) in Ember versions < 2.9.0.

<strike>The reason your controller is updated when you pass in named parameters and not when you pass in positional parameters is that named parameters are bound and positional parameters are not.</strike>

[I copied your example into an Ember Twiddle that illustrates the difference](https://ember-twiddle.com/70b9354dca1429a87ed728b71fa61c7b).

Comment: interestingly if we change ember version to alpha, then positional params too act like bound..is this correct or bug in alpha release?.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is interesting. 2.2.2 to 2.81 (release) don't have the bound behavior but alpha, beta, and canary do.

Comment: may be Glimmer2 be the reason

Answer (score 2):

It is best to avoid the two way binding and rely on separating the two actions. This is called **Data Down; Actions Up**. To illustrate your template might look like this:

```
{{test-component foo=bar update=(action (mut bar))}}
```

Then in your `test-component` component simply call the update action

```
this.get('update')(newValue);
```

In this way foo doesn't change until the parent does the change (from the `(action (mut bar))` line). It separates the concern about who owns the truth.

Obviously this is a rule of thumb that can be broken (see the `{{input}}` helpers for an example of breaking the rule). But you should know when and why your straying from the happy path when doing so. If you aim at writing all your components to not change the data they are given but instead trigger actions then it will make your application easier to reason about and maintain.